# Bind nth-child to array, Angular

Tags: angular

I have an array of numbers and a `<ul>` in my Angular application like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
     <ul>
        <li>Line: 1</li>
        <li>Line: 2</li>
        <li>Line: 3</li>
        <li>Line: 4</li>
        <li>Line: 5</li>
        <li>Line: 6</li>
        <li>Line: 7</li>
        <li>Line: 8</li>
        <li>Line: 9</li>
        <li>Line: 10</li>
        <li>Line: 11</li>
        <li>Line: 12</li>
    </ul>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  list: number[] = [2, 5, 7];
}
```

I want to select all `nth-child`'s that are in the list array, so the generated CSS should look something like this:

```
li:nth-child(2),
li:nth-child(5),
li:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can manipulate CSS selectors (nth specifically) with angular binding?

Comment: So just to clarify, adding a class to the `li` for each nth in your array is not acceptable ?

Comment: The list is dinamic, it can change

Answer (score 1):

If this list is dynamic like you said, then I think that something like this would be the best approach - [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6x1c1m).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
     <ul>
        <li *ngFor='let n of list' <!-- for each number in list -->
          [ngClass]='{"chosen": selectedList.includes(n)}'> <!-- apply class if n is in selectedList -->
          List: {{n}}</li>
    </ul>
  `,
  styles: [`.chosen{color: #f00;}`]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  list: number[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
  selectedList: number[] = [2, 5, 7];
}
```

Note the new definition of `list` and `selectedList`